# Eclipse Hadoop Plugin says "java.io.EOFException" while trying to connect

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, ubuntu, hadoop

- I am trying to setup my Eclipse for Hadoop using this [page](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/17%20-%20set%20up%20hadoop%20location%20in%20the%20eclipse.html)
- I am using hadoop eclipse plugin jar from [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1262)
- my core-site.xml looks like has the following:

> ```
>   <property>
>   <name>fs.default.name</name>
>   <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
>   <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
>   scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
>   uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
>   the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
>   determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
> </property>
> </configuration>
> ```

- my mapred-site.xml has following

> ```
> <property>
>   <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
>   <value>localhost:54311</value>
>   <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
>   at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
>   and reduce task.
>   </description>
> </property>
> ```

- I set up hadoop location under mapreduce perspective in Eclipse as

  > Location Name: local Map Reduce Master
  >
  > - Host: localhost
  > - port: 54310
  >
  > DFS Master
  >
  > - Host: localhost
  > - port: 54311
- When I try to connect it gives error saying:

> Error: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54311 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException

- Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: There is a probably a version mismatch. What is your Hadoop version? Can you post a bit more of the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately eclipse plugin is outdated, few months ago I managed to get it working properly,  but that was a nightmare, I had to change a lot of parameters there : (

I would recommend to use a web based hdfs browsing: go to http://localhost:50070 or any other host you have installed hadoop, and click on "Browse the filesystem" link (the first blue link from above), you will see all you need.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't had much problem. Googling will give you https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1280
Use the jar file in your eclipse

```
$ cat mapred-site.xml 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>localhost:8021</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I set the master to 8021 & DFS master to 8020.

I think you are doing the same mistake I was doing. Swap your port nos in your eclipse config and it should work

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's the problem of hadoop configuration. Maybe it was caused by the hadoop eclipse plugin.

When you create a hadoop project , which is not the type of Map/Reduce Project(the plugin provided project type). When you test the MapReduce code in this project with the hadoop eclipse plugin, it will throw EOFException.

The same code and same hadoop configuration runs successfully in the Map/Reduce project.

Comment: The question & the accepted answer already stated that its a problem with the eclipse plugin.

Comment: for each task we dont need to write map reduce.