# Hadoop Eclipse PlugIn Error: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54311 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, mapreduce, hadoop-plugins

I saw a similar question being raised one year ago. Here is the link:
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136859/eclipse-hadoop-plugin-says-java-io-eofexception-while-trying-to-connect)

I have similar configurations, but facing the same `EOFException` error.

Is it some problem with the Hadoop plugin for Eclipse or something to do with my Hadoop configurations? (NOTE: I have followed the standard configuration; so there is no chance of a mistake; Also when I run bin/start-all.sh the single-node Hadoop cluster is running fine)

Below is the stack trace from Eclipse while connecting to HDFS:

```
java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54311 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:775)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:743)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.createRPCProxy(JobClient.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:442)
    at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.server.HadoopServer.getJobClient(HadoopServer.java:473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.server.HadoopServer$LocationStatusUpdater.run(HadoopServer.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:446)
```

Hadoop NameNode Log is as follows:

```
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode STARTUP_MSG: host = somnath-laptop/127.0.1.1 STARTUP_MSG: args = [] STARTUP_MSG: version = 1.0.4 STARTUP_MSG: build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct 3 05:13:58 UTC 2012 ************************************************************/ 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,505 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,520 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered. 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,521 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s). 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,521 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,792 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered. 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,797 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists! 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,807 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered. 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,809 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered. 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,882 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type = 64-bit 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,882 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 17.77875 MB 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,883 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity = 2^21 = 2097152 entries 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,883 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hduser 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true   
2013-02-11 13:26:56,922 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,922 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s) 
2013-02-11 13:26:56,957 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,023 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,109 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files = 7 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,123 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files under construction = 0 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,124 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 654 loaded in 0 seconds. 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,124 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Edits file /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/current/edits of size 4 edits # 0 loaded in 0 seconds. 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,126 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 654 saved in 0 seconds. 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,548 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 654 saved in 0 seconds. 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,825 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameCache: initialized with 0 entries 0 lookups 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,825 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Finished loading FSImage in 923 msecs 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,830 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode ON. The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically. 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,838 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader: Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,845 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source FSNamesystemMetrics registered. 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,870 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort54310 registered. 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,871 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort54310 registered. 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,873 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Namenode up at: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 
2013-02-11 13:26:57,879 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,041 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,142 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter) 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,156 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = false 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,164 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50070 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,165 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50070 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50070 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,166 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50070 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,166 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,585 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,585 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Web-server up at: 0.0.0.0:50070 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,586 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,587 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,587 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,587 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 5 on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 6 on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 7 on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 8 on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:03,589 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on 54310: starting 
2013-02-11 13:27:07,306 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically. 
2013-02-11 13:27:07,308 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 7 on 54310, call delete(/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system, true) from 127.0.0.1:51327: error:  
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically. 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically. at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.deleteInternal(FSNamesystem.java:1994) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.delete(FSNamesystem.java:1974) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.delete(NameNode.java:792) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382) 
2013-02-11 13:27:14,657 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* NameSystem.registerDatanode: node registration from 127.0.0.1:50010 storage DS-747527201-127.0.1.1-50010-1360274163059 
2013-02-11 13:27:14,661 INFO org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /default-rack/127.0.0.1:50010 
2013-02-11 13:27:14,687 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode extension entered. The ratio of reported blocks 1.0000 has reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 29 seconds. 
2013-02-11 13:27:14,687 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: *BLOCK* NameSystem.processReport: from 127.0.0.1:50010, blocks: 1, processing time: 3 msecs 
2013-02-11 13:27:15,988 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping: got exception trying to get groups for user webuser org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: id: webuser: No such user at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:255) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182) at    
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getUnixGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:68) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:45) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:79) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getGroupNames(UserGroupInformation.java:1026) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.(FSPermissionChecker.java:50) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5210) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkTraverse(FSNamesystem.java:5193) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:2019) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getFileInfo(NameNode.java:848) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382) 
2013-02-11 13:27:15,988 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: No groups available for user webuser 
2013-02-11 13:27:16,007 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping: got exception trying to get groups for user webuser org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: id: webuser: No such user at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:255) at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getUnixGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:68) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:45) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:79) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getGroupNames(UserGroupInformation.java:1026) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.(FSPermissionChecker.java:50) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5210) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkTraverse(FSNamesystem.java:5193) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:2019) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getFileInfo(NameNode.java:848) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382) 
2013-02-11 13:27:16,008 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: No groups available for user webuser 
2013-02-11 13:27:16,023 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping: got exception trying to get groups for user webuser org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: id: webuser: No such user at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:255) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getUnixGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:68) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:45) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:79) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getGroupNames(UserGroupInformation.java:1026) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.(FSPermissionChecker.java:50) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5210) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPathAccess(FSNamesystem.java:5178) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getListing(FSNamesystem.java:2338) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getListing(NameNode.java:831) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382) 
2013-02-11 13:27:16,024 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: No groups available for user webuser 
2013-02-11 13:27:17,327 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of reported blocks 1.0000 has reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 27 seconds. 
2013-02-11 13:27:17,327 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 7 on 54310, call delete(/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system, true) from 127.0.0.1:51335: error: 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of reported blocks 1.0000 has reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 27 seconds. 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of reported blocks 1.0000 has reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 27 seconds. at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.deleteInternal(FSNamesystem.java:1994) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.delete(FSNamesystem.java:1974) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.delete(NameNode.java:792) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382) 
2013-02-11 13:27:27,339 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of reported blocks 1.0000 has reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 17 seconds. 
2013-02-11 13:27:27,339 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 54310, call delete(/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system, true) from 127.0.0.1:51336: error: 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of reported blocks 1.0000 has reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 17 seconds. 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of reported blocks 1.0000 has reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 17 seconds. at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.deleteInternal(FSNamesystem.java:1994) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.delete(FSNamesystem.java:1974) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.delete(NameNode.java:792) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
```

Any quick help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the web based hdfs web view work correctly? Have you followed [the SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11487419/283084)?

Comment: @harpun: Have added the namenode log. But it is not comprehensible

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by

- Make it `.jar` through Eclipse.
- Run in Hadoop `hadoop jar <jar_name> main_class_name`.