# why eclipse doesn't support new hadoop version

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I want to integrate hadoop with eclipse. While it seems eclipse plugin only supports old version of eclipse and hadoop,new version will cause an error about EOFException,detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136859/eclipse-hadoop-plugin-says-java-io-eofexception-while-trying-to-connect))I finish my configuration with Eclipse3.3 and hadoop0.20.0 and it works well. I want to know what should I do if I want to use new version of eclipse and hadoop, or other way to develop hadoop program.
Could anyone help me? Thanks very much~~